# Java convert Select to Enum

Tags: java, android, enums

in simple code i'm trying `enum` instead of `select` for example i want to convert this code:

```
switch (name) {
    case "1":
        return "a";
    break;
    case "2":
        return "b";
    case "3":
        return "c";
}
```

to Enum as:

```
public enum ContentTypes {
    FREE("1"),
    PAYABLE("2"),
    INCOME("3");

    private String name;
    ContentTypes(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public String getType(String type) {
    return (ContentTypes) type.getName();
}
```

problem is `ContentTypes` contents are values. for example

```
String test = "FREE";
getType(test);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't want to use something like a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead?

Comment: Have you tried `ContentTypes.valueOf(ContentType.class, type)`?

Comment: @PakkuDon i like to use Enum

Comment: @Ted Hopp no, please wait to test

Comment: @TedHopp thanks sir. problem resolve. please response to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `enum` type that you declare automatically gets a built-in static `valueOf()` method. There's also a static `Enum.valueOf()` method that you can use.

```
String name = "FREE";
ContentTypes t = ContentTypes.valueOf(name);

// or

ContentTypes t = Enum.valueOf(ContentTypes.class, name);
```

If I understand your requirement, you can build your solution on one of these API calls. Be aware that these methods are case sensitive and will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if `name` does not match an enum constant.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String name = ContentTypes.valueOf("FREE").name;
```